# UICalendarView in SwiftUI list does not render correctly

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I am having difficulties trying to display UICalendarView inside the list view. No matter what I do, the Calendar is always rendering outside the section bounds (like on the screenshot below, the last week is cut off). Ideally, I would like to have the calendar render inside the section view, with full available width and height that would adjust itself to fit all content.

[image: screenshot]

Here is my list view code:

```
    List {
        Section(header: Text("text")) {
            MyCalendarView()
                .scaledToFill() // .scaledToFit()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                // .frame(width: 200)
                // .frame(height: 400)
        }
    }
```

Here is my uikit calendar view code:

```
        let calendarView = UICalendarView()
        
        calendarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        calendarView.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        calendarView.tintColor = UIColor.tintColor
        
        view.addSubview(calendarView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            calendarView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            calendarView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
            calendarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            calendarView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
```

I am using a UIViewControllerRepresentable like so:

```
struct MyCalendarView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

  typealias UIViewControllerType = MyCalendarViewController

  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MyCalendarViewController {
    let viewController = MyViewController()
    
    return viewController
  }

  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MyViewController, context: Context) {}
}
```

Additionally, I get this warning:

```
[UICalendarView] UICalendarView's height is smaller than it can render its content in; defaulting to the minimum height.
```

Comment: You can't use UIViews in SwiftUI directly. You should use `UIViewRepresentable`.

Comment: I updated the question, I am using UIViewControllerRepresentable and it displays the calendar, it just won't size it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I was looking for was using horizontalSizeClass

```
@Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) private var horizontalSizeClass
```

and frame modifier with these parameters

```
MyCalendarView()
    .frame(
        maxWidth: .infinity,
        minHeight: horizontalSizeClass == .compact ? 400 : 500,
        maxHeight: .infinity
    )
```

Now the calendar is being resized/fitted correctly on all iOS devices.